# Gitlab-CI avoid unnecessary rebuilds of react portion of project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gitlab-ci

I have a stage in my CI pipeline (gitlab-ci) as follows:

```yaml
build_node:
  stage: Build Prerequisites
  only:
    - staging
    - production
    - ci
  image: node:15.5.0
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - http
  cache:
    key: "node_modules"
    paths:
      - ui/node_modules
  script:
    - cd ui
    - yarn install --network-timeout 600000
    - CI=false yarn build
    - mv build ../http
```

The UI however, is not the only part of the project.  There are other files with their own build processes.  So whenever we commit changes for only those other files, this stage gets rerun every time, even if nothing in the `ui` folder changed.

Is there a way to have gitlab cache or otherwise not rebuild this every time if there were no changes?  Any changes that should trigger a rebuild would all be under the `ui` folder. Just have it use the older build if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do in latest Gitlab version using the `rules:changes` keyword.

```yaml
rules:
  - changes:
    - ui/*
```

Link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#variables-in-ruleschanges

This will only check for changes inside the `ui` folder and trigger this stage.

Check this link for more info: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges

Comment: Will this work if a later stage requires artifacts from that stage (it takes the build files and puts them in a docker container using kaniko)

Comment: It should because if there are artifacts defined in this stage then when it is triggered it should be able to use that.